# Eclipse is not finding Nexus 4 or Nexus 7

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

I am not able to find my new Nexus 4 phone on windows 7. Previously I had used Nexus 4 then followed the instructions and able to find the device, later I had used another Nexus 4 phone which Im not able to find in the Windows7. Also Im not able to find Nexus 7.

Point is, I could only find the Nexus 4 which was installed initally and Im not able to find any other Nexus phone or tablets. Can anyone please help me to get this done.

Thanks

Comment: Have you activated the developer mode on the devices that are not shown?

Comment: Yes, I have enabled USB debugging option.

Comment: are you using the same usb cable?

Comment: Yes, Im using same USB Cable.

Comment: Try going to `Device Manager` and manaully using the `Update Driver` option to select the ADB driver for each of your new devices. I have to do this with every device I have to do this with every device I want to use on a given pc

Comment: I have updated the driver but no use.. later I have removed the driver and installed freshly again no use..  I have changed the USB computer connection to PTP(Camera), then Im able to find the device in DDMS. I dont know what is this. Anyway Im able to find the device in eclipse.. Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to install USB drivers only if you use Windows (If you're using MAC/Linux, most likely it will work fine without any driver installations)

in the following link they describe how to do it:

http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html

In short:

1. Connect your Android-powered device to your computer's USB port.
2. Right-click on Computer from your desktop or Windows Explorer, and select Manage.
3. Select Devices in the left pane.
4. Locate and expand Other device in the right pane.
5. Right-click the device name (such as Nexus S) and select Update Driver Software. This will launch 6. the Hardware Update Wizard.
6. Select Browse my computer for driver software and click Next.
   Click Browse and locate the USB driver folder. (The Google USB Driver is located in \extras\google\usb_driver.)
7. Click Next to install the driver.

Answer (score 2):

**Tutorial for driver noobs:**

Open Device manager.

Right Click on whatever resembles your device and choose update driver.

Then on the next screen click on `Browse Driver Software on your computer`

On the next screen click on `Let me pick from a list of device drivers on my computer`

From the list of drivers,Click on `Android Device` and then click next

[image]

Select `Android ADB Interface` and click Next.On the Next screen Click `Yes`

Answer (score 0):

Answering to my question for Windows:
Make sure you have kept the USB Computer Connection set to Camera(PTP).
Go to DDMS -> Reset your ADB. Your Eclipse should find the Device.

Hope this helps.